# Creating an HSQLDB Dump

Tags: mysql, sql, hsqldb

I would like to ask regarding an hsqldb instance that i have how it is possible to take a dump of the stored data for a specific table and insert that data into the same table of a similar database. I currently have an sqltool.jar with which i can make queries to the database, but i do not know the proper commands to take the dump. I would like to accomplish that without using a a graphical interface if possible.

Any suggestions would be extremely helpful, thank you in advance.

Comment: Read the Guide http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/